# Pandas df.drop when column value equals a certain value does not work as expected

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am running the following code to drop rows with a specific value in a column.  However, it seems to be dropping more rows than that contain the key. Full code and example given below

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 df=pd.DataFrame([['1','2','3'],['e','f','g'], ['a','b','c']], columns = ['start', 'middle', 'finish'])
 print('start',df,sep='\n',end='\n\n')

 def testAddColAndDelRow():
   #experiment in this line: df=df.copy(), df=df.iloc[:2,:2], df.iloc[:2,:2].copy(), nothing, ...
    df['newCol']=11
    df.drop(df[df['start'] == '1'].index, inplace=True)
    data_add = ['t', 's', 'q', 'p']
    df.loc[len(df)] = data_add
    return df 

 testAddColAndDelRow()
 print('df',df,sep='\n',end='\n\n')
```

I expect the following result.

```
e          f      g     11
a          b      c     11
t          s      q      p
```

But I get this - Where the row with a is also taken away. Does anyone know this this might be the case?

```
 e      f      g     11
 t      s      q      p
```

Answer (score 1):

You are rewritting row 2:

```
def testAddColAndDelRow():
    #experiment in this line: df=df.copy(), df=df.iloc[:2,:2], df.iloc[:2,:2].copy(), nothing, ...
    df['newCol']=11
    df.drop(df[df['start'] == '1'].index, inplace=True)
    print(df)
    print('-'*20)
    print('length of df: ',len(df))
    print('-'*20)
    data_add = ['t', 's', 'q', 'p']
    df.loc[len(df)] = data_add
    return df 

testAddColAndDelRow()
print('df',df,sep='\n',end='\n\n')



  start middle finish  newCol
1     e      f      g      11
2     a      b      c      11
--------------------
length of df:  2
--------------------
df
  start middle finish newCol
1     e      f      g     11
2     t      s      q      p
```

---

Your solution could be use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
def testAddColAndDelRow():
    #experiment in this line: df=df.copy(), df=df.iloc[:2,:2], df.iloc[:2,:2].copy(), nothing, ...
    df['newCol']=11
    df.drop(df[df['start'] == '1'].index, inplace=True)
    df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
    data_add = ['t', 's', 'q', 'p']
    df.loc[len(df)] = data_add
    return df 

testAddColAndDelRow()
print('df',df,sep='\n',end='\n\n')




start
  start middle finish
0     1      2      3
1     e      f      g
2     a      b      c

df
  start middle finish newCol
0     e      f      g     11
1     a      b      c     11
2     t      s      q      p
```

---

I recommend adding the last row before not having problems with the index and using [`Boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to delete the rows where start == 1 or '1'

```
df['new_col']=11
df.loc[len(df)]=['t','s','q','p']
df=df.loc[df.start.ne('1')]
print(df)
  start middle finish new_col
1     e      f      g      11
2     a      b      c      11
3     t      s      q       p
```

Answer (score 1):

First, be aware that repeatedly appending to and dropping from a DataFrame is almost never necessary. Odds are, there is a better way of doing things.

Now, assuming that this is purely for the sake of learning, here is how I would rewrite your code:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['1', '2', '3'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['a', 'b', 'c']], columns=['start', 'middle', 'finish'])

print(f'before test:\n{df}\n')


def test_rem_and_add(df_in_raw):
    df_in = df_in_raw.copy(deep=True)
    df_in.drop(df_in[df_in['start'] == '1'].index, inplace=True)
    df_in.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    df_in['new_col'] = '11'
    new_row = {'start': 't', 'middle': 's', 'finish': 'q', 'new_col': 'p'}
    df_in = df_in.append(other=new_row, ignore_index=True)
    return df_in


df = test_rem_and_add(df)

print(f'after test:\n{df}\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I used your code and got the results you expected. 
Using:
Python 3.7.4
pandas==0.25.2
numpy==1.16.4
gave me:

```
    start
      start middle finish
    0     1      2      3
    1     e      f      g
    2     a      b      c

    df
      start middle finish newCol
    0     1      2      3     11
    1     e      f      g     11
    2     a      b      c     11
    3     t      s      q      p
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: this is not the expected result since it contains the row where start is equal to 1. Precisely because of that because the row has not been filtered, it is therefore added correctly after the last row

Comment: He provided us with an incorrect test dataframe since it contains '1' and to use the `drop` method deletes comparing with 1 (no string)